# Google PageSpeed for http://fonts.googleapis.com/: Eliminate render-blocking JS & CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: wordpress, seo, pagespeed

I am testing a site on Google PageSpeed Insights and receiving the message: 
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

However the render-blocking "JS/CSS" are google apis (ie. http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400).

Is there a way to surpass this without causing styling issues? The googleapis come from different plugins/the theme (dynamically generated I believe).

For Mobile this is listed as "Should Fix:" aka in the RED.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Btw I already tried W3TC/Gzip and some other plugins. They helped for OTHER actual js/css but did not affect the google apis.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I wouldn't worry about it if it was just a small piece of CSS that was causing this issue. If it was JS then it is usually easy enough to move it to the bottom (inside) of the `<body>` element. That means it will simply be loaded after the pages content which is usually ok.

As for CSS, it isn't agreed by all that it should be moved from being in the head. For example, I believe [Yahoo suggests](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top=) keeping it within the head to make the page seem to load faster. Because what's the point of content loading before the styles.

Loading these in the header is probably the best idea because it usually only takes around 50ms or so, and means the fonts won't flicker after it is fully loaded.